# Flatten array with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array with arrays inside it. I would like to flatten it and get a single array with all the values.

```
let arrWithArrs = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
let array = arrWithArrs.map(arr => ...arr);
```

This obviously doesn't work but I would like to know how to make it work.
The wanted outcome would be

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) - ES2019

Comment: `let array = arrWithArrs.flat()`, just to exemplify ASDFGerte's documentation link.

Comment: What you describe is *not* [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's flattening arrays to remove other inner arrays. Destructuring assignments will take values out of arrays and specifically assign those to variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a reduce on the array to combine each of the arrays into a single array like so:
`arrWithArrs.reduce((result, lst) => [...result, ...lst], []);`